# Find $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin{(x^3 + y^5)}}{x^2 + y^4}$. Prove your result.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Find $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin{(x^3 + y^5)}}{x^2 + y^4}$.  Prove your result.

I've attempted to apply the Squeeze Theorem as such:
$\frac{-1}{x^2 + y^4} \leq \frac{\sin{(x^3 + y^5)}}{x^2 + y^4} \leq  \frac{1}{x^2 + y^4}$.  Clearly, though, the leftmost and rightmost functions of this inequality tend to $\infty$  as $(x,y) \to 0$, so this result does not help.

Comment: 87 minutes. $ $

Comment: @Did Between the asking and the first answering?

Comment: @Neal Something like that--but worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: A more precise estimate is based on $$|\sin{t}| \le |t|$$ Try using this estimate with $t = x^3 + y^5$.

Comment: Using your hint, I've concluded that $\frac{-(x^3 + y^5)}{x^2 + y^4}\frac{-|x^3 + y^5|}{x^2 + y^4} \leq \frac{\sin{(x^3 + y^5)}}{x^2 + y^4} \leq \frac{|\sin{(x^3 + y^5)}|}{x^2 + y^4} \leq \frac{|x^3 + y^5|}{x^2 + y^4}$

Comment: Disregard that last comment.  I've concluded that Using your hint, I've concluded that $\frac{-|x^3 + y^5|}{x^2 + y^4} \leq \frac{\sin{(x^3 + y^5)}}{x^2 + y^4} \leq \frac{|\sin{(x^3 + y^5)}|}{x^2 + y^4} \leq \frac{|x^3 + y^5|}{x^2 + y^4}$

Comment: In reference to the above inequality, how can I prove that the leftmost and rightmost functions converge to 0?

Comment: Use triangle inequality where you left off, then handle the two terms separately.  For example, $|x^3|/(x^2+y^4)\leq |x|^3/x^2$ and then can you do the rest?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another hint/warm-up problem:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^6+y^5}{x^4+y^4}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left|\frac{\sin(x^{2+\color{red}{n}} + y^{4+\color{blue}{m}})}{x^2 + y^4}\right|
\leqslant\left|\frac{x^{2+\color{red}{n}} + y^{4+\color{blue}{m}}}{x^2 + y^4}\right|
\leqslant\frac{|x|^\color{red}{n}\cdot x^2+|y|^\color{blue}{m}\cdot y^4}{x^2+y^4}
\leqslant|x|^\color{red}{n}+|y|^\color{blue}{m}
$$